# Are these really capacitors?

Tags: capacitor

I've bought a beginners' electronics kit, which has some electric components and things, and a book with several projects.
There is a list with all the components in the kit. There are 3 different capacitors in the kit:
[image]
3 100uF capacitors,
5 100nF capacitors,
5 100pF capacitors.
I know the 100uF ones, I've seen similar ones like them a lot in videos and inside some devices, and I know they come in different capacitance, so what are the other ones? And why do they looks very different from the usual capacitors? And why aren't they used as the usual shape capacitors?

Comment: They all look like capacitors to me. "Usual" capacitors is a function of your limited experience. To me they are all "usual".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types#Types_and_styles

Comment: @Andyaka yeah, I literally don't have any experience, I started learning one week ago

Comment: Don't let component size or shape fool you... everything has some amount of capacitance, inductance, and resistance. These three just happen to emphasize capacitance. They are made from different materials and by different processes, so are shaped differently and have slightly different characteristics and uses, but are all "capacitors."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're all very normal (albeit old-fashioned through-hole) capacitors of three different types. The cylindrical ones are electrolytic, good for high capacitance in a small space, but polarized and have a limited life. Used where precise capacitance value is not too important, such as power supply filters and non-critical coupling and timing.

The rectangular ones are film type, good for low leakage and moderate capacitance. Moderate stability with temperature.

The dipped ones are ceramic disk capacitors, good AC characteristics and good for small to moderate capacitance. At the 100pF level they also will have good stability with temperature.

Comment: Just to add a bit to Spehro's answer: you could write *books* (multiple) just about different capacitor types, their characteristics, why the currently available ones are still economically viable, why the obsolete ones are obsolete (and why they were economically viable back in the day), ad infinitum.  For learning, for the most part, you can just use any old cap with the right value.  But when you start reaching for high precision, or high power, or high frequency (or super-low frequency), you need to acquire an encyclopedic knowledge of capacitor types.